# How to force goroutine ordering for testing

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a concurrency utility which is essentially a wrapper around unbuffered
channels- providing `Send` and `Receive` functions with optional timeouts via
`context.Context`. Hence, the inside of the function has a `select` that looks
roughly like so (simplified for exposition):

```
func Send(ctx context.Context, ch chan interface{}, item interface{}) error {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    case ch <- item:
        return nil
    }
}
```

This code is tested and working, but there is an undesirable behaviour where if
the context has been cancelled *and* the channel can be written to, the send
will succeed or fail non-deterministically. This is intended behaviour of
`select`, so I added a non-blocking send before the main `select`, with the
expected behaviour that this first `select` should always succeed if the chan
is available.

```
func Send(ctx context.Context, ch chan interface{}, item interface{}) error {
    select {
    case ch <- item:
        return nil
    default:
    }
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    case ch <- item:
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am *reasonably* confident that this is a correct implementation, but I would
like to write a test case that attempts to exercise the event ordering.
However, due to the non-determinism inherent in dealing with multiple
goroutines, I cannot work out how to sequence events properly.

Here is what I would like to test:

```
func TestReceiveThenSend(t *testing.T) {
    ch := make(chan interface{})
    go Receive(context.Background(), ch)

    // Somehow, wait until the above `Receive` is blocked reading from `ch`.

    // Immediately expired context.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 0)
    defer cancel()

    if err := Send(ctx, ch, "foo"); err != nil {
        t.Fatal("expected Send to succeed because Receive is already called.")
    }
}
```

Obviously, I can't expect the above test to work since there is no ordering
between the `go Receive` and `Send`. I've tried various hacks such as forcing
`runtime.Gosched`, `time.Sleep`, or implementing a custom `Context` that knows
when its `Done` member is used. None of these can force the ordering that I
would like.

I'm stuck, I'm looking for any way, pretty or ugly, to force this behaviour.
Does anyone have any tricks to solve this?

Comment: why not  `ch := make(chan interface{},1)`?  not really need the `Receive` goroutine for the test case.